# Commands not running while one is in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, subprocess, command-prompt, popen

It was my belief that commands in discord.py run asynchronously, but for some reason, when I have one command running, the others just wait. Here is my command.

```
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True) 
    startCode = 'code'
    process = subprocess.Popen(startCode, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True) 
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
        line = line.decode()
        print(line)
```

All the top portion does is run a command which starts up a server. The for loop after that just reads off the response from command prompt line by line live. It works well but the line reading doesn't stop as long as the server doesn't stop, this means that it goes forever until I turn it off. This is leading to problems with my other commands as they just stop working whenever this one is running. How can I make it so all my commands run asynchronously with the above?

Comment: The line reading is probably not fully async. You could try running it in another thread, `iter` will repeatedly call the callable until it's either exhausted or equal to the second argument you passed there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to execute shell command on discord using `discord.py`, you can do this

````
import subprocess

@bot.command(name='shell', description='Console Remote')
@commands.is_owner()
    
async def _eval(self, ctx, *, cmd):
        # Ender : This very  damger dont give it to your friend ig D:<
        await ctx.send(f"Current Shell = {os.getenv('SHELL')}")
        results = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
        lmao = results.decode("utf-8")

        await ctx.send(f"```css\n{ lmao }```")
````

Edit the code if your wanna do it in another way

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what you want. `check_output` will stop the thread until whatever you're executing finishes.

Answer (score -1):

Because there are no return statement in the function, the bot will not run new commands if the previous one is not done.

To my limited knowledge, I think threading would help with this.